# C# Outlook AddIn: How to determine to which calendar an AppointmentItem belongs?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, appointment

I want to determine to which calendar an AppointmentItem belongs.

The scenario is as follows:

An exchange administrator can have privileges to create appointments for conference rooms (by simply creating an appointment in the conference rooms calendar) and for himself (in his own calendar). How do I determine wether the item that the administrator currently looks at (inspector) is from the conference rooms calendar?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If this is Outlook 2007-2010, compare MAPIFolder.Store of the MAPIFolder object returned by the AppointmentItem.Parent property.

Comment: I also need to implement the same functionality, But the store value is 'null'. Please advice.

Comment: If you have time, please read this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911510/getting-information-from-delegated-email-account-from-appointment-inspector-wind

Answer (score -1):

```
Outlook.Folder AppointmentFolder = appointmentItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
Messagebox.Show(appointmentItem.FullFolderPath);
```