# How do I get the Outlook calendar that an appointment is being made to

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, outlook-addin

I have created a personal calendar named *Time Tracking* in Outlook as well as my normal exchange calendar.  I have created a Form Region for a simple Outlook AddIn.  I want the form region to show only if the appointment is going/derived from the *Time Tracking* calendar.  Below is a screenshot of both calendars.

[image]

I want to show the form Region only when it comes from my Time Tracking calendar.

I tried this code:

```
public partial class TimeTrackingRegionFactory
{
    // Occurs before the form region is initialized.
    // To prevent the form region from appearing, set e.Cancel to true.
    // Use e.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
    private void TimeTrackingRegionFactory_FormRegionInitializing(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs e)
    {
        var appt = e.OutlookItem as AppointmentItem;
        if (appt != null)
            e.Cancel =
                !(appt.Parent as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder).Name.Equals(
                    Constants.TIME_TRACKING_CALENDAR);
    }
}
```

However, I found that the calendar name for both is 'Calendar'.  I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018485/c-sharp-outlook-addin-how-to-determine-to-which-calendar-an-appointmentitem-bel%20question) but I checked and both StoreID and Store properties seem the same.

If I save the appointment and then reopen it, it will say the appointment is from the *Time Tracking* calendar and then display the form region correctly from the code above.

It is like all appointments seem to be defaulted to the *Calendar* rather than *Time Tracking* calendar even though I'm trying to create one from there until it is saved.

Is there a way to find out what calendar the appointment item is being saved to?

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 0):

Look at the appt.Parent property - it will return the parent MAPIFolder object.

Comment: I do look at the Parent property: (appt.Parent as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder).Name but the Name is the same 'Calendar'.  Same with Store.  I do see there's a Folders property and the count is two.  Which is correct.  Would it help if I create some screenshots?

Comment: I've updated the question.  The appointment is being created as a normal outlook appointment (see screenshot above).  However, once I do save it, the above code will work as it seems to know that it is from the Time Tracking calendar.

Comment: Yep, Outlook creates appointments in the default Calendar folder and then moves them when Save is called. Is calling save an option for you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Is calling save an option'?  Ideally, I only want to show the form region if it is from the Time Tracking Calendar.  I'm not sure if there's some 'OnSave' event but I don't think that will work because it will be showing the form region anyway.  I might have to resort to some custom form that saves only to the Time Tracking calendar.

Comment: I meant if you can call AppointmentItem.Save before running your form logic. How are the appointments created in your folder? Are they created from the Outlook UI? Have you tried to retrieve the currently shown folder using Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder if the AppointmentItem.Parent test fails?

Comment: That's it! Thanks Dmitry for your persistence. Posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry Suggestion Works:

```
var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

e.Cancel = !(outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder).Name.Equals(
            Constants.TIME_TRACKING_CALENDAR);
```