# Getting information from delegated email account from appointment inspector window - outlook 2013 using addin-express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook, outlook-addin, delegation

I am developing an Outlook plugin using add-in-express. There are two mail account (A) which has granted calendar access to account (B) through delegation. I am developing the plugin for account (B).

**Here is what I want to implement.**

I open the calendar account of (A) after login to outlook using the credentials of account (B) (as a user, not by C# code). Then double click on some date of the calendar, which leads to open a new inspector window for me. 
In the ribbon of the inspector, there is a button coming from my pluging. After user click the button, I need to show the email owner’s (account (A)) email and name in the body of the inspector.

**Here is the code for the button**

```
    private void adxRibBtnDelegateTest_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
    {
        Outlook.Inspector currentInspector = null;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem myAppointment = null;
        Outlook.MailItem myMailItem = null;

        string ownerEmail = string.Empty;
        string ownerName = string.Empty;


        try
        {
            currentInspector = Globals.ObjOutlook.ActiveInspector();
            myAppointment = currentInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            myMailItem = currentInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

            Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = currentInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem ;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder parent = appt.Parent as Outlook.MAPIFolder;

            // ToDo:
            // Here I need to develop the functionality for getting the delegated account owner's email and name

            string body = "\n\nOwner's Email\t: " + ownerEmail
                + "\nOwner's Name\t: " + ownerName;

            if (myAppointment != null)
            {
                myAppointment.Body = body;
            }
            else if (myMailItem != null)
            {
                myMailItem.Body = body;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.DebugMessage(2, "Error in AddNewNationalCall() : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myAppointment != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myAppointment);
            if (myMailItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myMailItem);
            if (currentInspector != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentInspector);
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Can you please advise me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You may try to get the Store object and check its name (see the [Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863350.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Folder class). Typically the display name contains an email address (see [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866767.aspx)), but it is not a panacea.

I'd recommend using any low-level property viewer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy. They allow observing low-level property values (as well as OOM) you may access using the PropertyAccessor class. Outlook is just a big wrapper around Extended MAPI.